# Shapefile of continents not displaying correctly in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have a [shapefile](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11317GLSxu44QbO7Gv8ZomCaEqCUOOtXE) containing polygons that displays correctly in QGIS:
[image]

I would like to upload this as a shapefile to GEE and use as a mask to clip the JRC water extents to remove  the ocean water pixels near all the coasts.

However, when I upload the shapefile and plot the resulting table, it looks like this:
[image]

It apparently covers the entire globe, with Antarctica being inverted (not covered). The original shapefile had polygons for each continent, so I tried to dissolve this into a single geometry using QGIS's Dissolve tool, but I got the same result. The polygons have holes and are quite complex in some places.

I can share the shapefile if anyone wants to take a crack at it, but does anyone have ideas? I found a few notes about the clockwise/counterclockwise orientation of the vertices, but nothing definitive.

UPDATE:
Following a commenter's suggestion, I used Shape Escape to create a fusion table, and the result was as expected:
[image]

However, the original question remains: why doesn't GEE ingest/display the shapefile properly?

Comment: Have you tried to use [shape escape](http://www.shpescape.com/)?. And yes, could you share a file please?

Comment: I haven't used shape escape, but am trying it now. If it doesn't work, I'll upload the shapefile.

Comment: @Basile Thanks for the suggestion of using shape escape--it worked. The question still remains why it doesn't work when I upload as a shapefile, but for now I can progress.

Comment: Can you upload your shapefile so we can solve your problem completely?

Comment: @Basile added download link to first line in post.